# How to connect VoIp to Nodejs Server using Flutter

Tags: ios, node.js, flutter, apple-push-notifications, node-apn

am currently working on an application am using socket.io and node.js to carry out the real-time activity of the application, am using Agora.io for the voice and video call functionality.

**Package am Using**

```
  agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.7
  agora_rtm: ^1.0.1
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  flutter_callkit_incoming: ^1.0.0+8
  flutter_ios_voip_kit: ^0.0.5
  wakelock: ^0.5.6
  socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0
```

At the moment, everything is working very fine on **ANDROID** but not so well with **IOS**

**Below are some of the things I which to accomplish**

1)Make Calls from the app

2)The receiver can pick up his/her phone even when the phone is in the foreground or background

3)When the Reciever pick the call, take both the receiver and the caller to the call page

> The above features are already working perfectly on Android

**The Issue Am Facing on IOS**

1. I want the receiver to be able to receive calls when the app is in the background or when the device is on lock

**What have done so Far**

I did some research via Google, StackOverflow, GitHub, and Apple Developer articles,
in my research, I discovered that I need to get **VoIP Push Notifications Certificate** in order to receive notifications in my app

1. so I have downloaded the VoIP notification certificate added it to
   my keychain
2. have exported the certificate to **.p12** format
3. Have generated **.pem** from the **.p12**
4. Have downloaded the **.pem** from My Apple developer account
5. Have my Team Id
6. Have my Key Id

**What am I not getting Right**

1. How do I connect my flutter app to Nodejs for the purpose of sending notification requests to APNs?.
   I read through this GitHub repo, but I can't wrap my head around it [link](https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn)
2. Where do I get the Device token?
3. How do I receive the Voip token in my flutter App?

***Please I await your Help, am open to new ways as long it will make it work!***